# Automatically focus window on mouse hover only across multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, synergy, window-focus

I have multiple monitors setup on Windows 7.
I want a window to be focused only if my mouse hovered over it when coming from other monitor (this is how it worked when I used Synergy with multiple desktops)
I tried enabling Windows 7's auto focus feature from 'ease of use' under control panel.
It works fine, but removes a window's focus if mouse pointer is in same monitor but hovered over different window.

In short window should be focused only when mouse pointer is moved across monitors, not when mouse hovers over a window.

can this be achieved ?

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.